# Merging two Lists and a dictionary to create a single dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have two Generic lists having objects of class :

```
class Subject
 {
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

And another class as below :

```
class Student
{
    public string RollNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; 
}
```

And a List of type having Roll No and Subject codes as KeyValuePair for student as below :

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>  RoleList=
           new  List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> ();

Student st1=new Student();          
Subject sb1=new Subject();
Subject sb2=new Subject();
Subject sb3=new Subject();

RoleList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(st1.RollNo,sb1.Code));
RoleList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(st1.RollNo,sb2.Code));
RoleList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(st1.RollNo,sb3.Code));
```

What I need is another Dictionary of type

```
Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> StSbList =
    new Dictionary<string, List<Subject>>();
```

where StSbList should have a list of subjects for given student using dictionary RoleList having all the subjects for a given Roll No. using LINQ in C# 4.0 , something like

```
 StSbList(st1.RollNo, {sb1,sb2,sb3});
```

I tried and was able merge to similar collections but struck with different type of collections. Any suggestions on any other better approach.

As rightly pointed by Douglas and Martin, both the solutions are working fine but on my test data ToLookup works faster so used the same.

**Solution 1**

```
Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> stSbList =
RoleList.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
        .ToDictionary(
            grouping => grouping.Key,
            grouping => grouping.Select(kvp => (from sub in listSub
                                                where sub.Code.Equals(kvp.Value)
                                                select sub).First()).ToList(),
            EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
```

**Solution 2**

```
var tSbList = RoleList.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => 
             (from sub in listSub
              where sub.Code.Equals(kvp.Value)
              select sub).First());
```

Comment: Explain more clearly what you need, and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried my best to explain what I need, but If possible you can point me where I need to be more specific, I am happy to edit my question and about what I have tried I merged to lists and two dictionaries using some previous questions from here only.:)

Comment: What do you expect the `StSbList` to hold. Describe this more clearly. Also, we are not here to do your job, so please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: By the way, there are several `RoleList.Add(st1.RollNo, ...);`, but this is a **dictionary** and there `ArgumentException` will be thrown ("An item with the same key has already been added.").

Comment: Hi Steven, I am not asking anybody to do my work, no offences meant but I did not posted any code which I already tried using some other questions from Stack-overflow only just keep question clear. If you want I can post same code again.

Comment: @PanditA, could you please clarify, what is the relation between `Student` and `Subject`? I suppose, it is many-to-many relationship: each student can have many subjects and each subject is learnt by many students?

Comment: @Serge, Actually relation is like If a student has opted for a particular subject in a class, then based upon that his multiple profiles will be created but at the end what I need is a single list of subjects per student. The business objects are diif. I used subject and Student just to keep it simple.

Comment: @Serge, I have changed my question slightly just to the relation between Student and Subject. I hope It make some sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn’t really clear. If you’re asking for an example of how to populate your dictionary, here’s one:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> stSbList = new Dictionary<string, List<Subject>>();
stSbList.Add(st1.RollNo, new List<Subject> { sb1, sb2, sb3 });
stSbList.Add(st2.RollNo, new List<Subject> { sb1, sb3 });
stSbList.Add(st3.RollNo, new List<Subject> { sb1, sb2 });
```

More succinctly using nested collection initializers:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> stSbList = new Dictionary<string, List<Subject>>
{
    { st1.RollNo, new List<Subject> { sb1, sb2, sb3 } },
    { st2.RollNo, new List<Subject> { sb1, sb3 } },
    { st3.RollNo, new List<Subject> { sb1, sb2 } },
};
```

**Update**: As others have pointed out, your definition of `RoleList` as a dictionary is probably erroneous, since it will not allow you to define multiple subjects for the same student. What you need is a data structure that supports the representation of a many-to-many relation; for example, a `List<T>` of `Tuple<string,string>`, where `Item1` of each tuple contains the `Student.RollNo`, whilst `Item2` contains the `Subject.Code`:

```
var roleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st1.RollNo, sb1.Code));
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st1.RollNo, sb2.Code));
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st1.RollNo, sb3.Code));
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st2.RollNo, sb1.Code));
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st2.RollNo, sb3.Code));
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st3.RollNo, sb1.Code));
roleList.Add(Tuple.Create(st3.RollNo, sb2.Code));
```

To convert this into a dictionary, you could use first use the `GroupBy` operator, followed by `ToDictionary`:

```
var subjects = new[] { sb1, sb2, sb3 }.ToDictionary(sb => sb.Code);

Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> stSbList =
    roleList.GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item1)
            .ToDictionary(
                grouping => grouping.Key,
                grouping => grouping.Select(tuple => subjects[tuple.Item2]).ToList(),
                EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
```

**Update<sub>2</sub>**: For completeness, this is how to construct the dictionary from your definition of `RoleList` (although this probably isn’t what you want):

```
var roleList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
roleList.Add(st1.RollNo, sb1.Code);
roleList.Add(st2.RollNo, sb2.Code);
roleList.Add(st3.RollNo, sb2.Code);

var subjects = new[] { sb1, sb2, sb3 }.ToDictionary(sb => sb.Code);

Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> stSbList = roleList.ToDictionary(
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    kvp => new List<Subject> { subjects[kvp.Value] });
```

**Update<sub>3</sub>**: Adapted to work with the latest version of your code:

```
var subjects = new[] { sb1, sb2, sb3 }.ToDictionary(sb => sb.Code);

Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> stSbList =
    RoleList.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
            .ToDictionary(
                grouping => grouping.Key,
                grouping => grouping.Select(kvp => subjects[kvp.Value]).ToList());
```

Comment: I am not asking how to initialize a Dictionary. But the question is Using two lists and a dictionary merging them together on some criteria to get another dictionary which is composed of objects from one of the initial list.

Comment: @Douglas- Thanx for the update, I just edited my question to clear the confusion.

Comment: @Douglas- var subjects = new[] { sb1, sb2, sb3 }.ToDictionary(sb => sb.Code); for this part, I have List of Subjects and I directly need to use that.

Comment: @PanditA: You really should put more effort into formulating your questions properly if you expect people to help you. You’ve changed the content of your question at least 4 times (often giving blatantly incorrect code), and you’re saying it’s still incomplete? Where’s this list of subjects in your example?

Comment: @PanditA, then you should probably create the dictionary from that list. Looking up in a list like this would be slow.

Comment: @Douglas I mentioned regarding lists in very first line of my question. I will take care and will try to formulate my questions better.

Answer (score 2):

To get you desired dicionary you can use the [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) extension method.

You want to keep the `Subject` objects but in your question you seem to throw them away and only store their code in the dictionary. I have taken the liberty to slightly modify how you create `RoleList`:

```
var subject1 = new Subject { "Code 1", "Subject 1" };
var subject2 = new Subject { "Code 2", "Subject 2" };
var subject3 = new Subject { "Code 3", "Subject 3" };
var RoleList = new  List<KeyValuePair<string, Subject>() {
  "Roll 1", subject1,
  "Roll 1", subject2,
  "Roll 1", subject3,
  "Roll 2", subject2,
  "Roll 2", subject3
}

StSbList = RoleList.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Assuming that `RoleList` has the following data:

```
Key    | Value
-------+---------
Roll 1 | subject1
Roll 1 | subject2
Roll 1 | subject3
Roll 2 | subject2
Roll 2 | subject3
```

The `StSbList` will contain the following data:

```
Key    | Value
-------+-----------------------------
Roll 1 | subject1, subject2, subject3
Roll 2 | subject2, subject3
```

Comment: I think this misses one more step: the result should contain `Subject`s, not their codes.

Comment: @Martin Liversage : I need objects of Subject class not only subject code.

Comment: @Martin : I used below code but in grouping for any given code I am getting element count as 4 in my case whereas I had only three subjects. Last element it shows as NULL. My code is : var tSbList = RoleList.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (from sub in listSub
                                                    where sub.Code.Equals(kvp.Value)
                                                    select sub).First());

Comment: @PanditA: There are several answers that suggest you should use `.GroupBy(...).ToDictionary(...)` but `.ToLookup(...)` is really a simpler way of doing that. The confusing linear search inside the value selector of the `.ToLookup()/.ToDictionary()` can be avoided by storing the `Subject` objects in the source dictionary.

Comment: @Martin : LookUp is way to go...Neat solution..:) Thanx for the reply. As far as detour is concerned there are some old collections and can not be changed, hence the detour.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the desired dictionary it is necessary to create an associative storage for **subjects**.
Please take a look at the code.

```
Student st1 = new Student
    {
        Name = "John",
        RollNo = "Roll 1"
    };

Subject sb1 = new Subject
    {
        Code = "Subject 1"
    };
Subject sb2 = new Subject
    {
        Code = "Subject 2"
    };
Subject sb3 = new Subject
    {
        Code = "Subject 3"
    };

// Create the associative dictionary for subjects.
var subjectsByCode = new [] { sb1, sb2, sb3 }.ToDictionary(subject => subject.Code, subject => subject);

// Many-to-many relationship: Student (RollNo) <=> Subject (Code).
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> roleList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(st1.RollNo, sb1.Code),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(st1.RollNo, sb2.Code),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(st1.RollNo, sb3.Code)
    };

// Create Student RollNo => List of Subjects dictionary.
Dictionary<string, List<Subject>> studentRollNoToSubjects = roleList
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key) // Group by RollNo
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, // Key of the dictionary is RollNo.
        group => group.Select(pair => subjectsByCode[pair.Value]).ToList()); // List of subjects is created using subjects-by-code dictionary.
```